# how to upload image?

Tags: php

I want upload images in php here is my code

```
if (isset($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
  if ($_FILES['userfile']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $from = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $to = "/var/www/html/images/".$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $res = move_uploaded_file($from, $to);
    if($res)
    {
      print 'upload success';
    }  
    else
    {
      print 'fail';
    }
```

here i got output fail please tell me correct process

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you receive any error message on this? could you post your html code too?

Comment: check whether "images" folder have write permission to store images. are you getting any errors? use ini_set('display_errors','on') to see any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for `images/` have you checked the Permission on Linux it will be 755 or 777.

Note: You don't need absolute path for that you can even do like below.

```
$to = "images/".$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks OK, so either the script cannot write to unsifficient rights on the `/var/www/html/images/` directory, or that directory does not exist at all. 
Please check the existance of the directory, and then try to write another file (not through upload) to that directory. Check the directory permissions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it is already tested and working fine.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("kerala");
error_reporting(0);
?>
<?php
if($_POST[sub1]=="Upload")
{
@mkdir("image");
$link="image/".time()."-".$_FILES[fil][name];
copy($_FILES[fil][tmp_name],$link); 
$sql2="insert into `details`(`photo`) values('$link')";
$query2=mysql_query($sql2);
header("location:photo.php");
}
$sql3="select * from `details`";
$query3=mysql_query($sql3);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query3))
{
//echo "<a href=`$row[photo]`><img src='$row[photo]' height='100' width='100'>$row[photo]</a>";
echo "<img src='$row[photo]' height='100' width='100'>";
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="fil">
<input type="submit" name="sub1" value="Upload">
</form>
```